# A tool for stealthy recording screen videos

Tags: video, screen-recording, windows-server

I am looking for a tool to capture user's screen in form of videos (not screenshots), but I don't want the user to find it out that I'm recording the screen. Something like BB FlashBack, but not displaying the program's icon in tray.

- I want to install it on Windows Server 2016.
- I prefer freemiums or something allowing for purchasing an academic
  license (I want the software for an academic project), but if the
  price is reasonable, I guess I can manage that.
- The two features I'm looking for are:

  1. Being able to be passed on to the background. I don't want it to appear even in tray since that would cause problems in my research settings.
  2. I need it to record videos. I'm not looking for capturing screenshots.

Comment: Hope you have legal reasons to do so, recording without the users consent would be illegal in many countries, especially if you collect personal information.

Comment: My MA thesis project is an action/empirical research. I want to film the participant's behavior when working remotely. All the participants will be notified of participating in an action research after data collection and the data of those who disagree to inclusion in the research would be excluded from our work. 
My plan was to use BB FlashBack, but in the pilot test I found out that there's a chance that the curious participants would pay attention to its tray icon.

Comment: Couldn't you just hide the icon (windows taskbar settings) or arrange it so it is placed in the popup area (if enough other symbols use up the space)? If the participants agreed to the observation, it should be no problem that they _can_ discover the icon, it could only be a problem that it influences their behaviour if visible. Or is it a taskbar icon instead of a tray icon?

Comment: As I just mentioned, Martin, it's an action research, so basically, they should not be aware of participating in it in advance; they will be informed of that only after the test.

Answer (score 1):

Get [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) and hide the tray icon by a) Windows way as mentioned in comments or b) [Hiding trough OBS settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3LM8-gY31E).

OBS is compatible with lots of things, so I heavily recommend it, tough I can't test if it works with Windows Server 2016.

Comment: I tried it but couldn't make it run in background. On the other hand quality of the files it create is low.

Comment: You can also try hiding with AHK

Comment: If you can get something recording, then download autohotkey.com install it and create a hidemyrecorder.ahk (text file), edit it with the first line ' WinHide, MyAwesomeRecorderProgramTitle ' (title is the thing what is shown at a top of a window (in onurcano22's answer there is screenshot with 2 windows: create task and edit action)

Comment: Then another file for ' WinShow, AwesomeTitle '   hate how enter means post comment in android app.. sorry for multiple comments. You can also assign a hotkey to the command with ^+r::WinHide, AwesomeTitle (^Control, +Shift, !Alt, #WinKey then key, in that case r and :: is like then execute following)

Answer (score 1):

You might try Bandicam. But I must say you can't disable splash screen (as far as I know). Here you will find more information about starting and stopping the program [Bandicam timer recording information](https://www.bandicam.com/support/tips/timer-recording/)

[image: Bandicam, Auto Start Recording, Timer recording screenshot]

The page tells you to run "bdcam.exe" but I think using "bdcam_nonadmin.exe" would be better.

I guess starting the program without icon could be done with a vbscript file.  If you plan to use it we would help.